# Powershell Start and stop additional powershell instance foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script I am spawning additional powershell instances to run cmdlets.

I need to be able to `Start-Process` , a powershell instance, from a nested foreach loop and allow the process to run through and then stop that process when its complete.

```
foreach($thing in $things)
    foreach($stuff in $stuffs)
          start-process powershell.exe -nonewwindow | get-cmdichooseasanewcmd | export-csv -path stuff
          stop-process same instantiated process
```

How do I stop the process that is specifically tied to my foreach loop when it is complete with its task?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited to add my question. I hastily pressed ask question!

Comment: Is there a way to spawn multiple instances of powershell.exe to run my command and then exit the process when its complete?

Comment: "spawn multiple instances of powershell.exe to run my command" - why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not doing anything requiring credentials you can use jobs.

```
$job = Start-Job { # Do stuff }
$job.StopJob()
```

Anything involving credentials invokes the wrath of double hopping but I don't think it works the way you're running it in your question either so shouldn't be a problem.

Alternatively you can use runspaces but that's a big can of worms. See [this link](http://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/19/sharing-variables-and-live-objects-between-powershell-runspaces/) if you want to go there.

Comment: No but they are considerably more complex than jobs

Comment: and considerably more faster ;)